# Getting mouseclick events on a canvas

Tags: canvas, click, addeventlistener

I have been trying and trying to get my simple javascript script to move a bouncing ball to where a mouseclick event happened.  I have the script here.  It will interface with any canvas of any size with the id `game`.  The ball bounces but it ignores mouseclicks.  Do you know what's wrong?  Thanks.

```
var canvas;
var x, y;
var dx=4;
var dy=4;
var d = 20;
var width, height;

function init() {
    canvasE = document.getElementById('game');
    canvas= canvasE.getContext('2d');
    width = canvasE.width;
    height = canvasE.height;
    x = d+dx+1;
    y = d+dy+1;
    canvasE.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);

    clear();

    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.fillStyle="#0000ff";
    // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
    canvas.arc(x-1,y-1,d,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    canvas.closePath();
    canvas.fill();
    setInterval(loop, 15);
}

function loop() {
    clear();

    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.fillStyle="#0000ff";
    // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
    canvas.arc(x,y,d,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    canvas.closePath();
    canvas.fill();
    // Boundary Logic
    if( x<(d-dx)+1 || x>width-(d+dx)-1) dx=-dx;
    if( y<(d-dx)+1 || y>height-(d+dy)-1) dy=-dy;
    x+=dx;
    y+=dy;
}
function clear() {
    canvas.fillStyle="#ffffff";
    canvas.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    canvas.fillStyle="#888888";
    canvas.strokeRect(0,0,width,height);
}

function onClick(e) {
    var clickX;
    var clickY;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { 
        clickX = e.pageX;
        clickY = e.pageY;
    }
    else { 
        clickX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
        clickY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
    } 
    clickX -= gCanvasElement.offsetLeft;
    clickY -= gCanvasElement.offsetTop;
    x = clickX;
    y = clickY;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is more proper (though not 100% bulletproof) click code for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Lanc/

As a side note, using "canvasE and canvas" instead of "canvas and context/ctx" respectively for a naming convention might generate some serious confusion if you work along other canvas programmers. I would strongly suggest moving to "canvas and context/ctx".

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much!  What did you change to make it work?

Comment: Look at the differences in the onClick function. I had no idea what gCanvasElement was so I removed it.

Comment: Here is an updated version that uses `requestAnimationFrame()` instead of `setTimeout()` http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/4Lanc/367/